# Can JSF 1.1 be integrated into Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf

Most questions, examples, tutorials, etc. that deal with Spring Boot & JSF are for version 2.x.

Due to constraints, I can only work with our existing JSF 1.1.  This has been a pain point for quite sometime and integrating it with Spring Boot has seemed to cause more issues.

Our faces-config.xml is large so I'll just give a generic faces-config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer 
Faces Config 1.1//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Configuration">
    <!-- JSF VariableResolver that eventually delegates to Spring -->
    <application>
    <variable-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
    </variable-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

In all of the examples I've come across they are using the ELResolver but for 1.1 you need to use the DelegatingVariableResolver.  Are there any issues using this with SpringBoot?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I’ve tried using the DVR as I do in my regular spring/JSF project to no avail.  I can get JSF2 with the ELResolver to at least serve a simple JSF page.  Using 1.1 seems a bit more finicky.

Comment: Don't go this way, you'll run from one problem in another. Upgrade to jsf 2.2, less work